# How to suppress error output from @testing-library/react?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a test somewhat like this :

```
it('should fail when no provider specified', async () => {
  expect(() => render(<TestComponent />)).toThrow('Some error');
});
```

the test succeeds because the `TestComponent` does throw an error. However, there is also an error output

> Error: Uncaught [Error: Some error]

How do I "catch" this, or otherwise properly test the above `TestComponent` for errors?

#### ** EDIT **

I am currently going around the issue by replacing `console.error`:

```
const __logError = console.error;
console.error = () => {};

expect(() => render(<TestComponent />)).toThrow('Some error');

console.error = __logError;
```

However this solution seems clumky. Is there a clean way of doing this?

### ** EDIT **

I changed the implementation of `TestComponent` so it would catch the error instead of throwing, but there are still error output from Testing Library.

Here's the implementation :

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { hasError: true, error };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      hasError: false,
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    //console.error(error, errorInfo);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, error, hasError: true }));
  }
  
  render() {
    return this.state.hasError ? (
      <div data-testid="test">{ this.state.error.message }</div>      
    ) : (
      <SomeOtherComponentThrowingErrors />
    );
  }
};
```

And I changed the test case to:

```
await act(async () => {
  render(<TestComponent />);
});

expect(screen.getByTestId('test')).toHaveTextContent('Some error');
```

The test succeeds (as it did before), however there are still error outputs.

Again, the only way I can suppress the output is by replacing `console.error` and restoring it back after the test.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. Also I am not certain if this is a good approach to test components that throw. You should test via an `ErrorBoundary` component if the inner component (in your case `TestComponent`) did throw an error. That way you uphold the black box principle of react testing library. Coming to think of it, directly testing a component for throwing is testing implementation details.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß that's the thing. `TestComponent` does catch the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [detailed comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11098#issuecomment-412682721) from Dan Abramov on that. The code example of the final solution can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/adf9d5500e11a4e7b2c6f7ebf994fe56)

---

Some important quotes from this comment:

The problem

> **What Emits These Warnings?**
>
> We see two warnings:
>
> - `Error: Uncaught [...]`
> - `The above error occurred ...`
>
> The first one is coming from jsdom. The second one is coming from React.

And the solutions

> **How to Opt Out of the jsdom Warning?**
>
> What about the cases where you don't want to see it? In the browsers,
> you can opt out by calling `preventDefault()` in a custom `error` event
> handler on the `window` object.

> **How to Opt Out of Seeing React Component Stack**
>
> ... we won't print the stack if the error itself was silenced (as
> described above) and the error was handled by an error boundary.

Please, refer to the [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11098#issuecomment-412682721) for more details